# "Application-defined or object-defined error" Copying Charts to Powerpoint From Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have been using excel vba to copy and paste the charts in the excel file to the ppt file using below code.This is code i have tried in another application it worked fine but i used the same code in another application it throwing me the error "**Application-defined or object-defined error**" while pasting the chart1 into ppt.Can any one can tell me where i have done wrong and what changes need to be done.

```
Sub PasteToPPT(FileName As String)
Dim file As String
file = FileName

Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim AppPPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim SlidePPT As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject
Dim Sht As Excel.Sheets

Set AppPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    AppPPT.Visible = True

     AppPPT.Presentations.Open (file)

     'AppPPT.Presentations.Open FileName:=file

     Excel.Sheets("Charts").Activate

     AppPPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 1
        Set SlidePPT = AppPPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

     Excel.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart1").Copy '<-- Here i'm getting the error
         AppPPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste.Select

     AppPPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = False

    AppPPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 0
    AppPPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 275

    AppPPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 966
    AppPPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 200

    Excel.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart2").Copy
        AppPPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste.Select

    AppPPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = False

    AppPPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 0
    AppPPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 390

    AppPPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 966
    AppPPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 200

    'AppPPT.ActivePresentation.SaveAs ("D:\Projects\IEB MBU MYR US\Demo_Slide.pptx")
    AppPPT.ActivePresentation.Save

    Set SlidePPT = Nothing
    ''AppPPT.Quit
    Set AppPPT = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not having your workbook, it is difficult to debug. Are you sure that the chart's name is "Chart1" and not "Chart 1"?

Comment: I have modified the Chart 1 to chart1.

Comment: and still the same issue?

Comment: I have commented the chart1 containing data it works fine but the problem is when uncommented the chart1 code same error raises

Comment: I have worked another way and solved the issue.The Solution which i found is Excel.Sheets i have replaced with Excel.Worksheets and then error was resolved.

Comment: Ahh! Makes perfect sense now, should have thought of that... Great you figured it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Dinesh's comments, here is the answer in case somebody stumbles upon it later:

`Sheets("Chart1")` must be replaced with `Worksheets("Chart1")`.

The `Sheets` collection only contains real "calculation" sheets - but the `Worksheet` collection in addition contains chart sheets (and Excel4 macro sheets). As `Chart1` was a chart, it was not included in the `Sheets` collection...